# No chance to make an strongly typed object observable by mobx

Tags: javascript, typescript, observable, mobx, mobx-react

I use mobx library. It fit well with ReactJS.
I have and observable array like this:

```
@observable items = [];
```

When I add an object in this way, I have no problem and the given object will be observable as expected.

```
let x = {
Title: "sample title"
}

items.push(x);
```

but when I define an strongly typed object (using typescript)

```
export class SampleObject {
    Title: string;
    constructor(title: string) {
        this.Title = title;
    }   
}
```

and pushing new object in this way, It won't be observable

```
items.push(new SampleObject("Sample Title"));
```

How can I solve this problem !?

What's the differences between x and y ?!

```
var x = {
Title: "sample"
}

var y = new SampleObject("sample");
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: I got no error. items inside of the array isn't observable.

Comment: Seems odd, I can't see any reason for why this wouldn't work. Could you show us a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MobX only converts plain objects *automatically* to observable objects when assigning them to e.g. an array, because for class instances it might interfere with the internals of that class otherwise.

So in your class, just mark your fields (Title) as `@observable` as well and you should be good to go. See: https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/object.html, second bullet

Comment: Oh. That's not very intuitive.