# MobX React Not re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to implement a MobX - React App. But having trouble updating/ re-rendering the value. Store seems to load correctly and it is setting the initial value in the label. But any further value changes are not getting reflected.

**OrganisationNameStore** store :

```
import {action, observable} from 'mobx';
import OrganisationName from '../modules/OrganisationName';

export class OrganisationNameStore{
    @observable public orgName: OrganisationName = new OrganisationName();

    @action.bound
    public clear(): void{
        this.orgName = new OrganisationName();
    }

    @action.bound
    public handleTextChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
        this.orgName.name = event.currentTarget.value;
    }  
}

// Interface is required for TypeScript to be Type safe
export interface IOrganisationNameStore {
    orgName: OrganisationName;
    clear(): void;
    handleTextChange(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void;
    getOrganisationName(): string;
}
```

Parent Store file :

```
import { OrganisationNameStore } from './OrganisationNameStore';

// Have all the stores here
export const stores = {
    organisationNameStore: new OrganisationNameStore(),
};
```

OrganisationName class :

```
export default class OrganisationName {
    public name!: string;

    constructor () {
        this.clear = this.clear.bind(this);  
        this.clear();     
    }

    public clear(): OrganisationName {
        this.name = 'Mobx Text 1';            
        return this;
    }
}
```

Index :

```
import React from 'react';
import './index.css';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'mobx-react';
import { stores } from './stores/store';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider {...stores}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('root')    
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.tsx File :

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';
import {IOrganisationNameStore} from './stores/OrganisationNameStore'

interface IAppProps /*extends WithStyles<typeof styles> */{
  organisationNameStore?: IOrganisationNameStore // MobX Store

}

@inject('organisationNameStore')
@observer
class App extends React.Component<IAppProps> {
  constructor(props: IAppProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input
          type="text"
          // value={this.props.organisationNameStore!.orgName.name}
          name="name"
          onChange={this.props.organisationNameStore!.handleTextChange}
        />
        <div>
          <label>{this.props.organisationNameStore!.orgName.name}</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

tsconfig.tsx :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es6",
      "dom",
      "esnext.asynciterable"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

.babelrc :

```
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"],
    "plugins": [
      "transform-runtime","transform-decorators-legacy"
      // ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
      // ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }]

    ]
  }
```

There is no console errors.

Expected behavior - I wanted the label value to be updated when ever i type in the input in the App.tsx file.

Please correct me if i am wrong in implementing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as mweststrate said here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39959958/829154

> MobX only converts plain objects automatically to observable objects when assigning them to e.g. an array, because for class instances it might interfere with the internals of that class otherwise.
>
> See:
>   https://mobxjs.github.io/mobx/refguide/object.html, second bullet

so you should mark `name` as @observable in your OrganisationNameStore class.

Comment: Thank you @ehssan-majdabadi.

export default class OrganisationName {
 ** @ observable ** public name!: string;

Fixed the issue